# When the datanode in cluster Apache IoTDB already removed and stopped, how to export its data?

Tags: export, apache-iotdb, iotdb

If a DataNode in the cluster of Apache IoTDB is removed and stops running, can I export the data in this node? The Datanode cannot be started now but there is data in the data directory. Can this be done, for example, with the tsfile export tool provided in IoTDB(for the node closing situation)? Also, how should this operation be done?

I want to export data from a stopped datanode, but I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `load` command to load the tsfile of the old datanode into the new cluster of Apache IoTDB. The execution of `load` command is not relevant with the status of your old cluster, so it still can be used even if the datanode or the cluster is not started.